# Pass a Request.QueryString into a xslt doc

Tags: xslt

I have a URL that looks like this:

```
www.example.com/careers/job.aspx?jobTitle=analytics-developer
```

And I would like to pass the 'jobTitle' into an xslt file using `<%=Request.QueryString["jobTitle"]%>`

The code I am using in job.aspx to pass information to the jobTitle.xslt file is this:

```
<asp:Xml ID="Xml1" runat="server" DocumentSource="~/_/xml/Jobs.xml" TransformSource="~/_/xslt/jobTitle.xslt"></asp:Xml>
```

Where Jobs.xml is the xml file with all the job info.

Jobs.xml looks sth like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<jobs>
    <devjobs>
      <job>
        <title>Analytics Developer</title>
        <group>Mobile Analytics Group</group>
        <url>analytics-developer</url>
        <shortdesc>We are looking for talented developers.</shortdesc>
     </job>
  </devjobs>
</jobs>
```

Basically I want to be able to write in the xslt file that "if the `url` element from the Jobs.xml file is equal to the 'jobTitle' given in the url then we show that job's details".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The asp XML control has a "TransformArgumentList" property which can be used to pass paramters to your XSLT. To be honest, I don't know if you can it directly on the asp:xml tag itself, but you can always set in your code behind, in the page_load event, for example

```
protected void Page_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string param = Request.QueryString["jobTitle"];
    XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
    args.AddParam("jobtitle", "", param);
    Xml1.TransformArgumentList = ags;
}
```

Then, in your XSLT file itself, you would need to have a **xsl:param** element accordingly:

```
<xsl:param name="jobtitle" />
```

You can then access this just like any variable (by refering to it as **$jobtitle**).